# Does this picture show an Arizona fire department extinguishing a fire in Mexico?

Tags: fire, mexican-border-wall

This was posted by the Swiss news portal watson.ch:

[image]

Comment: This would be a better question if you quoted any text that described the photo, and/or linked the post.

Comment: If they did that and googled *Arizona fire department extinguishing a fire in Mexico* they wouldn't need to ask because the first hit is Reddit. Its top, 8.6k+, comment is *This happened in 2012.* and links to the original article written by Manuel C. Coppola for Nogales International on May 10, 2012, and not just some guy named "Dave" in 2019.

Comment: Why is this a notable claim which invites skepticism? Seems at most like a mildly interesting claim which invites curiosity.

Comment: Neighboring towns' fire departments often have reciprocal help agreements, even across borders.  This: https://www.cnn.com/2007/US/11/14/border.firetruck/ made the news when post-9/11 immigration checks held up a Quebec fire truck from entering the US to assist with a blaze.

Comment: The article OP mentioned is https://www.watson.ch/!556353724 which cites this reddit cross-post as a source: https://www.reddit.com/r/Mujico/comments/fuccd5/pinch%C3%A9_fuego_fugas/ and a few steps later we find this: https://www.nogalesinternational.com/news/blaze-in-nogales-sonora-battled-from-both-sides-of-the/article_3267761e-9b0d-11e1-85e7-001a4bcf887a.html

Answer (score 57, accepted):

Yes. At Nogales, Arizona, in 2012, according to [this](http://comfortcrumb.blogspot.com/2019/05/six-years-ago-but-still-important-today.html) story, found using Google Image Search:

> Nogales, Arizona, firefighters rushed to the international border with
> Mexico at Morley Avenue after a blaze broke out at the Hotel San
> Enrique in Nogales, Sonora, Mexico. The hotel had been a lodging for
> migrants waiting to cross illegally into the United States.
>
> The building was empty at the time of the fire and no injuries were
> reported. About 10 firetrucks responded from the Mexican side of the
> fence, while Nogales Fire Chief Hector Robles dispatched the local
> department's $827,000 ladder truck for its maiden trip to an actual
> fire.

The Nogales, Arizona fire department have helped the Nogales, Sonora, Mexico fire department on [other occasions](https://www.kold.com/2018/12/18/only-kold-no-politics-cross-border-fire-rescue/):

> December 17, 2018 at 10:08 PM MST - Updated December 17 at 10:08 PM
> NOGALES, AZ (Tucson News Now) - A 20-foot high fence with mesh and
> razor wire divides sister cites Nogales, Sonora, Mexico and Nogales,
> AZ. It’s a border, but it doesn’t stop the relationship between both
> fire departments along the border. A relationship that came in handy
> during a fire this past weekend.
>
> On Friday, Dec. 14 firefighters in Nogales, Arizona saw smoke. They
> called it in, thinking the fire was on the American side. Crews
> arrived and discovered the fire was actually on the Mexican side of
> the border. There was an issue though for the firefighters in Mexico,
> they didn’t have water flowing to the hydrants.
>
> The firefighters from Arizona acted fast and helped out their
> counterparts across the border. They hooked up a hose to a hydrant.
> Ran the hose to the fence, and there crews ran into another issue. The
> mesh fence that is about 7-feet high with sharp edges. The edges could
> cut the hose.
>
> One of the captains decided to lay a ladder on the mesh fence. So the
> hose would not get damaged and it worked. They tossed the hose to the
> firefighters in Mexico and they were able to put water on the fire.
>
> It took the firefighters several hours to put the fire out, but out of
> the three homes that were burned, only one was destroyed.
>
> Tucson News Now spoke with the fire Chief of the Mexican fire
> department about the two departments working together. He says the two
> have been helping out each other for years.

Comment: Looks good.  [Google Streetview](https://www.google.com/maps/@31.3326377,-110.9420348,3a,75y,94.55h,99.06t/data=!3m6!1e1!3m4!1surCQBkZmJB46TvOgZp6Hlg!2e0!7i13312!8i6656) seems to give a reasonable match for the buildings in Nogales, with the picture taken the Mexican side of the fence,

Comment: I've been here in person. As of July 2019, the buildings that they are spraying down here still look awful and falling apart.